# how to build program execution loaders

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, executable, elf

Comrades, I'm in a team that was instructed to develop a dummy kernel and I'm to build a loader, to load instructions from an executable file into memory for execution. We are using ELF object files. Can anyone provide a sample c/assembly code that illustrates the fetching of instructions from the executable file to the loading of the instructions into memory, or even a website that has such a tutorial. Thanks in advance

Comment: So broad that it's beyond the telling.  Look at open-source loaders, Linux maybe.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have just [downloaded this file](http://www.bitwagon.com/rtldi/rtldi-0.94.tgz "Download loaders"). But I'm yet to test it. Truly really broad